# Delaying while loop and refreshing contents of Div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content3">
<a href="" id="content2">Survey</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is picking href value from some hidden field in background.Initially when my web page opens href attribute of anchor tag is blank because the field is blank. There is some background process which populates the field with link. Now the process can take any time from 10 sec to 5 minutes. So i refresh the contents of div after 5 seconds and check weather href is blank or not. If it is blank then i disable the link and change the color of the link to the blank. But as soon as i refresh the contents of the div the link gets enable even though it is blank and its colour also changes to blue. Can someone help me with it.

```
       var a = document.getElementById("content2").getAttribute("href");
       let i = 0;
       if (a.trim().length < 1) {
       $('a[href=""]').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       })
         document.getElementById("content2").style.color = "black";
       task(i);
       }
       function task(i) {
       setTimeout(function() { 
       if (a.trim().length < 1) {
       $( "#content3" ).load(window.location.href + " #content3" );
       document.getElementById("content2").style.color = "black";
         $('a[href=""]').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       })
       document.getElementById("content2").style.color = "black";
         task(i+5);
       }
         else {
            document.getElementById("content2").style.color = "blue";   
         }
       }, 1000 * i);
       }
```

Comment: A couple of points of style: (1) you should indent your code properly to make it easier to read and maintain, and (2) if you are using jQuery, try to use it more consistently rather than a mix of pure javascript approach and jQuery approach (*e.g.*, `var a = document.getElementById("content2").getAttribute("href");` vs `var a = $("#content2").attr("href");`)

Comment: thanks for the review. I will incorporate the changes in my code

Comment: At first glance, I noticed that you set the click event in two places. Note that when you set the event, it remains set until you remove it from the element or change it. If you want an `href` that keeps you on the same page, use `href="#"` rather than `href=""`.

Comment: I'm curious about your time interval. Your code keeps adding 5 to the timeout interval, so it will first check immediately, then after 5 sec, then after 10 sec, etc. Is that your intention?

Comment: In actual the value of href is being populated from a dynamic variable. So unless the value of that variable is blank the link must be disabled.

Comment: i want to refresh contents of div after every 5 seconds

Comment: You are calling `setTimeout` with `i+5` for the time. You should just use 5 if you want it 5 sec each time. I also noticed that in your `task` call, you never refresh the value of `a`. It's always going to be the value you first set it to when you loaded (or reloaded) the page.

Comment: $( "#content3" ).load(window.location.href + " #content3" ); automatically refreshes the value of a.

Comment: I think `$( "#content3" ).load(window.location.href + " #content3" );` should be `$( "#content3" ).load(window.location.href + "#content3" );`. That shouldn't have any bearing on your problem, though.

Comment: You need to simplify the design a bit. When you load the page the first time, you set `a` and you have a javascript timer sequence setup. When you load the page again into the `div` of the page, that's a new javascript environment separate from that of the main page, so they have their own independent timers running and their own separate values of `a`. Also then the `div` contents will have id's that are the same as that in the main page. You should avoid loading a page into a portion of itself.